# Sfdisk NVME issue, No such device or address

Tags: partition, disk, lfs, nvme, sfdisk

I have custom LFS installer which contains sfdisk, I am trying to add support for NVME disks on it. When I make partitions with sfdisk on a normal SATA disk, things go as expected but when I do the exact same on a NVME disk, it creates the partitions, but when I am trying to get the size of a partition (with the `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p1` command), it outputs `No such device or address while trying to determine filesystem size`.

lsblk output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN SIZE TYPE
nvme0n1     259:0   1.8T disk
|nvme0n1p1  259:1   200G part
`nvme0n1p2  259:10  1.6T part
```

sfdisk usage:

```
,200G,L
,,L
```

/proc/partitions

```
major minor #blocks    name
259     0   1953514584 nvme0n1
259     2    209715200 nvme0n1p1
259     3   1743798343 nvme0n1p2
```

They are also listed under /dev as `nvme0n1`, `nvme0n1p1` and `nvme0n1p2`.

Now if I use `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p1` I get the output: `209715200` and `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p2` gives: `No such device or address while trying to determine filesystem size`.

Now the strange thing is, if I create the partitions again, and I do `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p1` this now gives: `No such device or address while trying to determine filesystem size` and `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p2` gives 209715200.

And if I it again over and over, it keeps changing, one partition is usable, other not, it swaps constantly.

Things I tried:

- Other SSD (same type), same result;
- I am using a pcie adapter for the NVME disk, tried other adapter, same result;
- Using the adapter in a running open suze installation, I can execute these comands with no issues;
- Normal sata drive, no issues.

[edit] I figured out after a reboot without the partitioning the drive again, it is possible to execute these commands, is this important to a NVME disk, but seems not to normal sata?

I am quite out of ideas now what to try or what the couse of this could be, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a sollution so I am adding the answer here so it might help others in case they encountered a similar problem.

I used the `blockdev --rereadpt /dev/nvme0n1` command. This rereads the  partition table, and now I can execute the `sfdisk -s /dev/nvme0n1p2` command with no issues without the need of a reboot.

I am still not sure why this is not needed with normal sata drives, so if someone knows why this is not the case, feel free to leave a comment.